# Android Notification Action: pending Intent not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm having issues with Android Notification's Actions.
Here's my idea:
My `BroadcastReceiver` wakes up upon a broadcast, then it creates a notification.
This notification should:

- open `MainActivity` when tapping its body
- share a message when tapping the button "Condividi"

I managed to get the `ACTION_SEND` working when tapping the notification, but i had no luck for the `action`...

Couldn't find anything on the web, only `pendingIntents` that open activities.

Here's my code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static int notificationId = 0;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("AlarmReceiver","ricevuto " + intent.getAction());
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String tipo = "sconosciuto";
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_flag_black_24dp);
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ALARM_ACTION_PALINDROM)){
        tipo="palindromo";
    }
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ALARM_ACTION_DOUBLE)){
        tipo="simmetrico";
    }

    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Orario " + tipo + "!");

    String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());
    mBuilder.setContentText(currentTime);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

    Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Sono le " + currentTime +", " + tipo + "\u2764");
    Intent shareIntentWithChooser = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent,"Send to");

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notifIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent pendingIntentShare = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,notificationId,shareIntentWithChooser,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_send_black_18dp,"Condividi",pendingIntentShare);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
    notification.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS|Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId,notification);
    notificationId++;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance, i really can't wrap my mind around it!

Comment: For starters you should use `getActivity` instead of `getBroadcast`, since you want to start an activity with the share action. Also there is no need to provide your main activity when creating it, since you want to 'chose' it later

Comment: I understood the first part of your comment and it solved my problem (so... add an answer so i can flag you as "problem resolved" :) )
But the second part is not clear to me. What do you mean "provide your main activity when creating it"? They are two different intents, one for share and one for activity...

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure if that was the only problem. Forget the second part though, I mixed up some lines of code! :)

Comment: Allright then! Thank you again! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `getActivity()` instead of `getBroadcast()` to create your `PendingIntent`, since you want to start an `Activity` with `ACTION_SHARE` and not send a broadcast.